# Finding the acute angle between the planes $x-3y+2z=14$ and $-x+y+z=10$

Tags: linear-algebra

> The two planes in this image form an acute angle. What is its value?

[image]

Well, that's a confusing drawing. I don't even know why are there two $\theta$s there (or what do $S_1$ and $S_2$ even mean). Anyway, here are the equations:

$$x-3y+2z=14\\
-x+y+z=10$$

The angle is

$$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{(1,-3,2)\cdot(-1,1,1)}{||(1,-3,2)||\cdot||(-1,1,1)||}\right)$$

That's like $107.97$ degrees. That's clearly not acute. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I didn't check your work, but if it is correct just substract $\;180^\circ\;$ to the result you got and change sign. As simple as that.

Comment: May be angle is $180 - 107.97$?

Comment: You could just as well have picked the normal $(1, -1, -1)$ to the second plane (which we could write as $x - y - z = -10$), and this choice gives the acute angle.

Comment: Again I didn't check your work, but you can reverse one of the normal vectors, and then perform dot product again to find the supplementary angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the acute angle between two planes, then place absolute values in the numerator. $$\theta_{\text{acute}}=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\color{red}\vert\,\vec{n_1}\cdot\vec{n_2}\color{red}\vert\,}{||\vec{n_1}||\cdot||\vec{n_2}||}\right)$$
The reason why this works is that this returns the angle where the cosine is positive, and that is between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ rad.

Answer (score 1):

No you did not do anything wrong. You just calculated the complement of the required angle.

Comment: What do you think about @Timbuc's comment? About $180 - 107$?

Comment: Yes he is right.

Comment: It all depends upon the choice of normal direction.